# Aggregate? values in a column, based on an entire list of rows from another table, repeatedly, where column names match second table

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, aggregate

Wordy title...but not sure how to describe it.
In the most basic sense, I think I am trying to aggregate, but it seems like maybe it's a loop of aggregating?  (Which leads me here, because everything I read says don't use loops in R.)

I have two dataframes:

```
df1
ID  ID2  Ball  Ball  Ball  Square  Square  Triangle  Triangle  Triangle
1   a    1     1     0     0       0       1          1         0
1   b    0     1     0     1       1       1          0         1
2   a    1     1     0     0       0       1          1         0
3   a    1     0     1     1       0       0          1         0
3   b    0     1     1     1       1       0          1         1
4   b    0     1     1     1       1       0          1         1
5   a    1     0     1     1       0       0          1         0
5   b    0     0     0     1       1       1          1         1
6   a    0     0     1     1       0       1          1         1
6   b    0     0     0     0       1       1          1         0
7   b    0     1     0     1       1       0          1         1

df2
ID  ID2  Type
1   a    Ball
1   b    Triangle
2   a    Triangle
3   a    Square
3   b    Ball
4   b    Square
5   a    Ball
5   b    Square
6   a    Ball
6   b    Triangle
7   b    Ball
```

These are all generic values. The ID's are much more complicated and not numbers, and the data structure is a couple hundred columns by 30,000 rows.

What I am trying to do though is sum up the columns based only on where the ID Types' from  df2 matches the column header in df1. But I have identical column names, and that is tripping me up a bit.

For this set, my desired output would be:

```
df3
    Ball  Ball  Ball  Square  Square  Triangle  Triangle  Triangle
Sum 2     3     3     3       2       3         2         1
```

Each column is only summed based on the matching ID's. So any column named Ball, only summed the rows matching ID 1, 5, and 7 listed in df2. (etc for each Type.)

Ultimately I want to then create a second table that collapses the first table down to simple averages:

```
df4
Ball  Square  Triangle
2.67    2.50     2.00
```

I hope this makes sense! There would be two data frames created from this.

EDIT:  I have edited my data sets to include the second ID, as well as stretched df2 to illustrate that it has more rows than df1 has columns. The Type in df2 is not a 1 for 1 match in df1. The column headers in df1 are for assigning what group Type that entire data set belongs to.

Comment: df1 is in wide form while df2 in long form, do have any specific format that you like? Because if it does not really matter, one thing I can suggest you could do is to make your df1 to look like df2 and then it would be easier to group them by type.

Comment: @Yon_P, would that still be the case when I have my full dataset that is 200 columns by 30,000 rows?

Comment: I just read your edit. Have you tried joining df1 and df2? Are the combination of ID, ID2 and Type in df2 unique enough that you can merge both df1 and df2 by ID and ID2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Type <- as.character(df2$Type)

ag <- sapply(2:ncol(df1), function(i) sum(df1[[i]] * (Type == names(df1)[i])))
tapply(ag, names(df1)[-1], mean)
##     Ball   Square Triangle 
## 2.000000 2.500000 1.333333
```

or

```
Type <- as.character(df2$Type)
nms <- names(df1)[-1]

ag <- mapply(function(x, nm) sum(x * (Type == nm)), df1[-1], nms)
tapply(ag, nms, mean)
##     Ball   Square Triangle 
## 2.000000 2.500000 1.333333
```

or:

```
nms <- names(df1)[-1]
Type <- as.character(df2$Type)

ag <- colSums(df1[-1] * outer(Type, nms, "=="))
tapply(ag, nms, mean)
##     Ball   Square Triangle 
## 2.000000 2.500000 1.333333
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines1 <- "
ID  Ball  Ball  Ball  Square  Square  Triangle  Triangle  Triangle
1   1     1     0     0       0       1          1         0
2   0     1     0     1       1       1          0         1
3   1     1     0     0       0       1          1         0
4   1     0     1     1       0       0          1         0
5   0     1     1     1       1       0          1         1
6   0     1     1     1       1       0          1         1
7   1     0     1     1       0       0          1         0
8   0     0     0     1       1       1          1         1"
df1 <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

Lines2 <- "
ID   Type
1    Ball
2    Triangle
3    Triangle
4    Square
5    Ball
6    Square
7    Ball
8    Square"
df2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, working through these now.  It always amazes me how simple the code looks, and how I have no idea how it works!    The first example errors out because It's not letting me skip the first two column names. (Which I just realized makes my demo data set not work. I will update that now.)    And the second one is giving me what I believe are the averages, but tells me there are over 50 warnings.  (I need to see how I can break out the sums before the average as well since I need to store those values.)   Haven't gotten to the third one yet.   Thanks!

Comment: Copy and paste the reproducible input in the Note at the end and then copy and paste the answers. There are no warnings or errors.

Comment: I updated df1 and df2. That might make a little difference.

Comment: If you have 2 id columns rather than the 1 id column originally shown then replace -1 with -(1:2) and replace 2 with with 3.

Comment: the warnings are: `In x * (Type == nm) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` I believe this is because I provided a data set that had an equal amount of columns in df1 to an equal amount of rows in df2. Unfortunately this not the case. I updated my question with a longer df2 and an explanation as to why in the EDIT section.  (I am currently working with the second solution you provided. I will try 1 and 3 to see if they have similar errors.)

Comment: All three of your solutions work on the provided demo data, but not on my real data. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: Bonehead move on my part, I was loading dataframes with unequal rows. My df1 is a subset of a much larger dataset, and for some reason I was thinking your code could subset out what I was looking for in that larger dataset. I just needed to create a true filtered subset like the df1 provided. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For the record:  The sapply answer works in .15 seconds, the mapply in .17 seconds, and the colSums in .74 seconds.